# Inserting user provided content into a document--validating HTML string, insertAdjacentHTML and iframe usage?

Tags: javascript, html

If I want to accept HTML built by a user of an extension, and not from a web source, and display it within an existing extension document, is there an alternative to using an iframe?

For example, if a user provides mathematical expresions using MathML and they are to be displayed in the current web page, and the user may add a `<div>` or `<p>` tag inaccurately and have incomplete HTML, how can it be added to the page without corrupting the layout of the page, apart from an iframe?

Does `insertAdjacentHTML` really accomplish this? This MDN [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) seems to imply so, where it reads, `"It does not reparse the element it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element."`

Or, is there a way to validate the HTML string before inserting into the DOM, such as `DOMParser`?

Also, for users that are knowledgeable in HTML, CSS, JS and can construct a small interactive document rather than just an expression, to be dislayed within the page, is an iframe the only option? The user provided code will be stored in indexedDB and rendered only on the user's machine and within this extension tool. So, something similar to a snippet on stackoverflow. I have this working in an iframe now but the user could add about a dozen of these to the page at any one time and I wondered if there is a better way of accomplishing this, regarding memory usage and in general.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are fine memorywise with a dozen iframes

Comment: Try it for yourself: try inserting `</div></div></div></div>` or something with `insertAdjacentHTML`, and see what happens.